# Units of Function

Tags: functions, exponential-function, physics

What will be the unit of a function $f(V)=e^V$, where $V$ is in Volts? I mean what will be the unit when the function is written in an implicit format and what will be the units when function has a logarithmic or exponential.

Comment: The expression for $V$ should be dimensionless, e.g. normalized with a reference voltage.

Comment: i think seeing the wider context of the question would be of great help here

Comment: Are you talking about the diode equation?

Answer (score 6):

If you're raising $e$ to the power of a physical unit then something has gone wrong—the exponent should be a pure number. So you might have something like $$V=V_0\cdot e^\frac{t}{T}$$

with $\frac tT$ being the ratio of two times.

In electronics that might be

$$V=V_0\cdot e^{-\frac{t}{CR}}$$

where $t$ represents time, $C$ a capacitance and $R$ a resistance—but when you work it out, $CR$ turns out to have the dimension of time: in fact it's the time a  capacitor of value $C$ would take to discharge to $\frac1e$ of its original voltage through a resistor of value $R$. So the exponent $-\frac{t}{CR}$ is still just a ratio, not needing physical units. And when you exponentiate it, what comes out is just a numerical value.

The exponent needs to be a pure number since otherwise, exponentiating gives a physically meaningless result.

For example, suppose $x$ represents a length. What does $e^x$ represent? Expanding its power series:

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+...$$

$1$ is a number, $x$ is a length, $\frac{x^2}{2!}$ is an area, $\frac{x^3}{3!}$ is a volume, $\frac{x^4}{4!}$ is a hypervolume . . . The individual terms represent things which it's meaningless to add together. And the only way to avoid this is to make sure that $x$ is a *dimensionless quantity*, i.e. one that can be expressed just as a number without any physical unit.

Comment: +1. The question was legit IMO. Zero tolerance for physics from some part of algebraic community is understandable. Just saying. Just an opinion.

Comment: @KenDraco Thanks! One thing I've *not* answered is that happens if we break the exponent up while manipulating it. I think this might be what the questioner actually meant (and the reason my answer has had a few downvotes).

Comment: @KenDraco And I think the simplest answer to that is probably that we can set the equations up in purely numerical terms just by having "a resistance of $R$ ohms" etc. Manipulate the equations as required and the units are irrelevant to mathematical validity of the manipulation—but have to be physically meaningful when inserted at the end.

Comment: I think they downvoted just physics here. It's especially clear from $-1$ votes the OP received. I mean it's even put on hold. I gave it a vote but it's a drop in the bucket. I mean they have their reasons and I respect that. Here is the best community on the whole SE. It's just that I'm not fond of dismissing (putting on hold) total beginners' questions or confused people. Yet, a lot of times such beginners (and not just beginners) don't care about theory, logic, derivations, and understanding. They just want a quick solve. They don't want to understand anything.

Comment: @John Cena, yeah, I understand that very well. It is a good valid question IMO, and I upvoted it and put it in favorites -- I don't want all physics-related or applied questions wiped-out. As I said in previous comments physics is not much appreciated here, and that's VERY deplorable. Books on calculus have lots of physics in fact, let alone ODE/PDE books. What's more, boundaries between book exercises and some real world applications are not that clear-cut. It's all just approximations. Well, the math community on SE is the best. Things just can't be perfect, esp. in online threads :-)

Comment: @JohnCena For the record, the units of expressions like $e^v$ puzzled me for a long time when I studied electronic engineering, which is why I wanted to answer the question when I saw it.

Comment: @KenDraco I think the hardest part of real world maths problems is often the translation into mathematical terms and back. So really, questions about physical meaning ought to be very welcome.

Comment: @KenDraco While I really can't speak for the rest of the community, I personally have nothing against physics questions, and this *could* have been a good question. The reason it was downvoted and closed is most likely because it is a question asked without context. See the link in the closure reason if you're confused.

Comment: @jgon, you're welcome.

Comment: @John Cena, please check my literature recommendations on physics/calc (plz don't scoff at precalc books or physics by Vuille) + you may use something like Electric Circuit Theory and Technology by Bird only after all the main books of calc/physics. Good books can help you understand everything if that's the goal (they are not overly rigorous, targeting physical aspects/applications). Point being: You can only yourself gain true knowledge -- people can't give you true knowledge in a few postings, although this answer was pretty good and crystal clear. You’re not gonna get that often anyways.

Comment: @John Cena, I wouldn’t be so sure without physics and ODE books on the list while jumping right on to a more advanced text by Chua at al. If you are plowing through Chua, then physics/calculus and this blocked question should be child’s play. But a general formal text is not necessarily the right path for grasping the fundamentals. Don’t get me wrong here: Chua is not bad, nor is Apostol bad for calculus. They are great books, but just not perfect for the Key Basic Knowledge like this blocked question. 
And I wouldn’t constrain myself with only one book on circuits in your place anyway

Comment: @John Cena, I’d start with Fundamentals of Circuits by Alexander and Sadiku + Electric Circuit Theory and Technology by Bird but it is even more imperative of what should be done before: University Physics by Young and Freedman + ODE by DiPrima + Linear Algebra by Kolman. Just as important and prior to that all are Precalc. by Larson + Physics by Vuille or something like that. This is advice for gaining true understanding, not for getting good college grades. It’s a lot and you’ll have to cut back on some of the material and prioritize on the other.

Comment: @John Cena, My more detailed take on math/physics textbooks (not for grades /GPA) is still on the SE Math (one of my answers), but choices are not cut in stone. Everybody tells me they studied and know precalc and guess what? They can’t derive FTC and (uv)’ in calculus; v^2/r in physics; or sin (x+y) in trig. And that is ridiculous for crying out loud! No disrespect meant but to understand things you need a firm grasp of main derivations and concepts in physics and math, otherwise how to study ODE and then to go into circuits? Don’t even know why I’m posting this. Probably totally useless.

Comment: I think a lot of us learn basics after learning, but remaining hazy about, more advanced stuff: we learn a load of magic formulas and what to use them for, then pass exams by knowing how to use them, but skip over the basics until we explicitly go back and study them out of confusion or curiosity. I'm trying to do that at present with some of the stuff I did at university—I loved maths at high school when it was something one *did*, then went off it when it was something one *remembered* (trig formulas, substitutions for integrals). Reexamining basics turns it back into something one does.

Comment: And it's surprising. My ideal is that (Euclid-like) I should be able to prove any theorem I use, right back to absolute basics, and there are lots of little "obvious" or taken-for-granted things that actually, I have to work out proofs for.

Comment: @JohnCena Totally agree.